# Hama m360 Wireless IP Cam Setup Nightmare

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, webcam, ip-camera

I have set up IP Cams before, although it has been a while.

Recently a friend of mine wants me to help him set up a **Hama m360 IP Camera**.

I have read the instruction for so many times I could even recite it.

But I have not been successful connecting the cam to my netbook.

Here is the **instruction**:

- Upon first set up, connect your cam to your PC / Notebook via LAN (RJ-45).

The default IP Address of the Cam is **192.168.2.3**

- If your router does not have the IP Address within the range (i.e. 192.168.xxx.xxx), which I have, you would need to go to (Windows XP) Network Setting -> LAN
- Then: **right click on "Properties" for TCP / IP**

select: **"use this IP Address"**

**Enter:**

**IP: 192.168.2.5 (why 192.168.2.5, when the default IP is 192.168.2.3???)**

**Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0**

**Click "OK"**

Once the above is done:

- Go to your browser: enter: **192.168.2.3** (why still the default IP Address for the IP Cam, when "**192.168.2.5**" has been done from the above step???).

***Nothing shows.***

***But*** when I tried to connect the IP Cam directly to the router, I can see it both in the router setting and in Web Browser.

However, I had to first look up its IP Address in the router (because I am using DHCP)

For example, if it shows up as "**192.168.2.9**" in my router, then I would enter this in to the web browser and I can see and move around the camera fine.

And then I would try to set up its WLAN properties through the Web Browser (with LAN still connected to the router).

But once the LAN Cable is pulled out from the router, WLAN does not work.

Please have a look at this [instruction from Hama website for this model](https://de.hama.com/00053116/hama-m360-wireless-lan-ip-camera-150-mbps-h264) (English starts at page 18)

I hope someone can give me a hand on this. It has been driving me nuts. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally.

After days of submerging (literally) myself in this realm of headache, in which IP addresses were as daunting like little zombies trying to crawl up on you, I finally got it running.

And I would love to share this, in case someone in the future would walk this path.

What I learnt:

- You don't really have to change the IP Address of the web cam, if your router provides this range (i.e. if it is 192.168.2.4 and if it is within the range of the DHCP pool from your router), this step can be skipped.
- In my case, this is a Hama IP Cam, but the software didn't work for me (thanks to bad programmer). But after searching online for the whole night, I came to realize that most of these different brands of IP Cams use the pretty much same install software with only a little variance from the same company (in my case here: Edimax). So I downloaded this software although the IP cam is by Hama. And it worked.
- What I also realized is this: always use IE to install because most of them require Active X / Direct X. If it doesn't work, go to microsoft and download DirectX and install it.
- Using the install software, set up the IP Cam using static IP.
- The most tricky part is to go from LAN (easy) to Wireless LAN (which caused my headache).
  After you set everything up using LAN with the RJ-45 cable still attached, do a ping (in Windows, click "Start" and in Search Box, search for "cmd"; to those who are unfamiliar, it is a little black-and-white screen) with option -t (hence, if the IP of your Cam is 192.168.2.3, do: ping 192.168.2.3 - t).

And as it keeps pinging, pull out the Ethernet (RJ-45) Cable from your IP Cam (most of the time, the automatic switch from LAN to WLAN will be activated just by pulling out the cable, if it's not in your case, then pull the cable out then flip a switch to WLAN).

- With pinging still running, you will see it loses connection after you have pulled out the cable and then in a swift starts again to pick back up responses in WLAN mode - if you get this - you win.

The positive side going through this would be, I'll say, the fact that you would be more familiar than ever remembering and understanding the IP Addresses in your network. So, when you are at your beloved local IT store next time and a salesman comes up to you and says "Are we interested in home networking? Let me introduce you this 200 USD router and this service plan of ours.. that would only cost merely 80 USD" - You could be able to throw at him with your "192", "168", "0", "1", a "Default Gateway" and finally with a "Subnet mask" and say: "I guess I can manage, thanks though".

But the most important of all these I have learnt is: walk away from it when you get stuck and come back at it later - this worked for me, as well.